# ¿Cómo mapear un objeto de JPA en un array en spring boot?

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

Buenas a todos: tengo un problemilla que quisiera que me ayuden a resolver.
mi problema es el siguiente, tengo que encontrar las distacias más próximas de las tiendas en un punto en el mapa de googlemaps según el radio que le de y según la latitud y longitud, en fin, ya tengo el query que me hace eso,
mi problema es cuando hago la llamada al `jparepository` me devuelve un array y necesito que me decuelva con ciertos valores

Este es mi end-point que estoy intentando sacar del `jparepository`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/promos/distance/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<?> distance(@RequestParam(required = false) Double latitude, Double longitude, Long radius) {

            try {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                        .body(locationDAO.findDistance(latitude,longitude,radius));

            } catch (Exception ex){
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(ex.toString());
            }
        }
```

Y este es mi repository el cual ya tiene el query con los parámetros de entrada

```
@Query(value = "select sp.id as id, \n" +
            "          ( 6371  * acos( cos( radians(:latitude) ) \n" +
            "      * cos( radians( sp.latitude )) \n" +
            "      * cos( radians( sp.longitude ) - radians(:longitude)) \n" +
            "      + sin( radians(:latitude) ) \n" +
            "      * sin( radians( sp.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance \n" +
            "        from promo_locations sp \n" +
            "having distance < :radius ORDER BY distance ASC", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> findDistance(
            @Param("latitude") Double latitude,
            @Param("longitude") Double longitude,
            @Param("radius") Long radius);
```

Y me devuelve de esta manera

```
[
    [
        1,
        137.94383549078196
    ],
    [
        2,
        137.94383549078196
    ]
]
```

Pero no es el formato correcto, tiene que devolverme así:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "distance" : 137.94383549078196
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "distance" :137.94383549078196
    }
]
```

Si alguien sabe cómo mapear le agradecería un montón
he intentado ya de varias formas pero nada

Comment: Mapea tu tabla en una clase, y en tu repositorio en lugar de regresar una lista de `Object`, regresas la lista de tu entidad creada: `List<Tabla> findDistance(...`

Comment: el problema es de que no es una tabla, es una consulta que hace ciertas operaciones amtematicas para sacar distancia, ya intente mapear lo que devuelve el query en una tabla pero no resulta

Comment: Parece que tu problema esta en el tipo de datos que retorna locationDAO.findDistance, puedes agregar que tipo de objeto esta retornando, para poder hacer un ejemplo de la conversión.

Comment: Espero que aun te sirva mi respuesta, no me llego notificación que habías agregado el Repository por eso no había contestado hasta ahora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es, primero especificar el tipo de datos porque con Object es dificil saber que retorna, debes cambiar por `Object[][]` con esto pasamos a tener una matriz de Object, para el ejemplo puede realizar la conversión a un Objecto especifico o a un Map, te dejo ambas formas::

Primero: Creamos un objeto que cumpla con el formato json que quieres.

```
public class DistanceDTO {
    private Long id;
    private Float distance;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Float getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(Float distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

Segundo: Te muestro una clase para realizar una simulacion:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.*;

public class DistanceToObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Al hacer el cambio de Objecto a Object[][] en el Repository tendrias esto.
        Object[][] dataRepository = {{1, 137.94383549078196}, {2, 137.94383549078196}};
        System.out.println("Json Incorrecto: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(dataRepository));

        // Conversion a objeto
        List<DistanceDTO> response = new LinkedList<>();
        Arrays.stream(dataRepository).forEach(data -> {
            DistanceDTO distanceDTO = new DistanceDTO();
            distanceDTO.setId(convertToLong(data[0]));
            distanceDTO.setDistance(convertToFloat(data[1]));
            response.add(distanceDTO);
        });

        // Conversion a LinkedHasMap
        HashMap<String, Object> responseMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Arrays.stream(dataRepository).forEach(data -> {
            responseMap.put("id", data[0]);
            responseMap.put("distance", data[1]);
        });

        // En el caso del servicio REST seria: return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);
        System.out.println("Json Correcto Object: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(response));
        System.out.println("Json Correcto Map: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(responseMap));
    }

    private static Long convertToLong(Object o) {
        String stringToConvert = String.valueOf(o);
        Long convertedLong = Long.parseLong(stringToConvert);
        return convertedLong;
    }

    private static Float convertToFloat(Object o) {
        String stringToConvert = String.valueOf(o);
        Float convertedFloat = Float.parseFloat(stringToConvert);
        return convertedFloat;
    }
}
```

> Json Incorrecto: [[1,137.94383549078196],[2,137.94383549078196]]
>
> JsonCorrecto Object: [{"id":1,"distance":137.94383},{"id":2,"distance":137.94383}]
>
> Json Correcto Map: [{"id":1,"distance":137.94383},{"id":2,"distance":137.94383}]

Como puedes ver el problema esta en que el Repository retorna una Matriz y no un hasmap. Espero y te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono de maravilla